# static member std::function of template class gets empty despite initalization

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, std, std-function

Consider the following class:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct Test
{
    Test() {
        if (!f) {
            f = []() { std::cout << "it works\n"; };
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
    static void check() {
        if (f) f();
        else std::cout << "f is empty\n";
    }
    T x{};
    inline static std::function<void()> f;
    inline static bool initialized = false;
};
```

An object of such class, if declared globally (*Yes, I know it's a bad practice to use global variables*), seems to empty the function `f` after it is initalized. The following example demonstrates this:

```cpp
Test<double> t;

int main()
{
    t.x = 1.5;
    std::cout << "t.x = " << t.x << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "initalized: " <<  Test<double>::initialized << "\n";
    Test<double>::check();
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
t.x = 1.5
initalized: true
f is empty
```

I expected `Test<double>::check();` to print `it works`.

However, the above example works as expected, when I do either of the following:

- declare `t` within `main()`
- do not use template for `Test` (just replace `T` with `double` for example)
- make `f` and `check()` be not static
- use plain function pointer instead of `std::function`

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: @miloszmaki It works with clang but does not work with gcc.:)

Comment: Interesting :) I was using gcc.

Comment: You didn't initialize it. You do assignment in constructor. Which might play games with caching\optimization. Note, the assignment would happen every time object is created, which defeats purpose of static member.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Right, I meant assignment not initialization. However, the assignment happens only once because of `if (!f) { f = ... }` condition.

Comment: @miloszmaki and you  are creating possible weak point because that's not an atomic operation. Why do that if language got exactly same mechanics properly implemented natively and atomicly? I mean, that would be static member initialization.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Agreed. Well, I presented here a simplified example for the sake of question's clarity. Originally I had a more complex code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is related to the order of initialization of static variables which I guess is solved differently for the templated instantiated static variables compared to `Test<double>` on different compilers.

```
inline static Holder f;
```

is a static variable, so somewhere before entering main it will be default initialized (to an empty function). But `Test<double>` is another static variable that will get its own initialization before entering main.

On GCC it happens that

- `Test<double>` is called
- `Test<double>::f` is set by the constructor of `Test<double>`
- the default constructor of `Test<double>::f` is called, thus emptying the function

This all happens inside `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` GCC method, if you actually use a wrapper object to break on static initialization of the variable you can see what's happening: https://onlinegdb.com/UYEJ0hbgg

How could the compiler know that you plan to set a static variable from another static variable before its construction? That's why, as you said, *using static variables is a bad practice* indeed.

Comment: Specifically the dynamic initialization of static data members which were instantiated from a template is completely unordered with any other dynamic instantiation. And even worse, it is implementation-defined whether the initialization of an `inline` static data member is deferred until its first non-initialization odr-use which would here happen only when `check` is called.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution to my problem. Instead of using a static variable `f`, one can define a static function creating the necessary static variable when used for the first time:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct Test
{
    Test() {
        auto &f = getFunction();
        if (!f) f = []() { std::cout << "it works\n"; };
    }
    static void check() {
        auto &f = getFunction();
        if (f) f();
        else std::cout << "f is empty\n";
    }
    static std::function<void()>& getFunction() {
        static std::function<void()> f;
        return f;
    }
    //...
};
```

Comment: That's a singleton\factory approach and it may have some overhead  (of checking status of local static variable)

Answer (score -4):

When you call

```
 Test<double>::initialized
```

and

```
Test<double>::check();
```

the constructor Test() was not called, hence the undefined content of both variables `initialized` and `f`

What you might wanna do is probably calling them

```
t.check();
t.initialized;
```

Comment: The constructor was called when the global t variable was initialized before entering main.